# How will I write a Jelly script for BUILD_LOG_REGEX in Jenkins/Hudson Email-Ext Plugin?

Tags: regex, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, jelly, email-ext

I am trying to write/modify a **jelly** script in Jenkins Email-Ext that returns the build log. I am trying to filter the log with **BUILD_LOG_REGEX** for regular expressions. Can someone give me a sample script or format for doing build_log_regex using jelly script template? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The default template that you can use as your starting point is located in

```
$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/email-ext/WEB-INF/classes/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly
```

Answer (score 0):

The `${BUILD_LOG_REGEX}` token is used in the Default Content section of email-ext and typically not inside of the Jelly script.  To use it, just change your Default Content to reference this token:

[image]

The developer of email-ext recommended switching from Jelly to Groovy since they have "more power, its easier to use and you can prototype stuff in the script console to some degree".

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin#Email-extplugin-Scriptcontent

You can then look at the source code for [`BuildLogRegexContent`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/content/BuildLogRegexContent.java) class on how this token is implemented and write code to produce exactly what you want.